# Change behaviour of nested_form's link_to_add function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

When using Ryan Bates's nested_form you can add another entry of the field with

```
<%= f.link_to_add "Add another Qualification", :qualifications %>
```

So if my form has this

```
<%= f.fields_for :qualifications do |build| %>
<%= build.label :qualification, "Add Qualification" %>
<%= build.text_field :name, :placeholder => 'Add Qualification Here' %>
<%= build.link_to_remove "Remove this Qualification" %>
<% end %>
```

when clicking Add another qualification i get the label and text_field repeated, how can i only repeat the text_field so I only have one label even if there are say 5 text fields

Is there a way to modify the Jquery being used as at the moment i call it via

```
//= require jquery_nested_form
```

In my application.js

Thanks

Comment: I would just remove it. And have a <p>Add Qualification</p> on top of the form.

Comment: Can you post your link_to_add function? It may have the extra stuff there that is not desired.